# How can one care for the Quran when travelling?

Tags: quran, travelling

I frequently travel and take a hard copy of the Quran with me. When ever I pack, I pack it in a nice piece of cloth and keep it on top of other books and clothes. But my bag is kind of loose and once it's on the move, things start to shift their position. If its gets inside the airport baggage, then it really gets tossed around. I hope you get the picture.

How can one care for the Quran when travelling?

I am seeking advice on how to carry around the Quran when traveling (whether it be by land, air or water). Some days when I busy, the Quran is actually inside my bag, probably under many stuff. I feel really uncomfortable keeping it that way. Anybody with a similar experience, if you have a good solution, please share.

Comment: Do you worship the book of Quran? Not sure why you seem to care so much about how it is stored?!

Comment: @AmericanMuslim. It is among the manners of the Quran to treat it with atmost respect. When you keep it on a shelf, it is kept on top of all books. So similarly in the case of packing, I was just wondering what to do.

Comment: Anyone can say anything. Revering the Quran is borderline shirk. We respect it, but not worship it.

Comment: You should know that putting the Quran inside the airport baggage seems to me a lot more convenient then carrying it with you, as you may lose tahara or go to toilette etc. And you should know that there are ahadith prohibiting to travel to non-Muslim land with the Qur'an!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Can you mention this Hadith? AFAIK the Prophet(pbuh) send his disciples to foreign lands(Non-muslim) for Dawah. I don't think they left without the Quran.

Comment: In both sahihs and the muwatta' you'll find http://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/199 but i also found this fatwa http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/11111

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks for the link. And about the Hadith, it says hostile land. That is not the same as Non-muslim Land.

Comment: I know, but some scholars do interpret it as a hostile land! But as we know we might find nowadays many copies of the Qur'an in non-Muslim countries and there were some copies and translations already spread in Europe a few centuries ago!

Answer (score -1):

```
               IN THE NAME OF ALLAH, THE MOST COMPASSIONATE, THE MOST MERCIFUL
```

As much as I found out what you mean, about

> Caring for the Quran during travel

I presume that you'd better swap your bag and buy a more appropriate one which can be more safe to keep the holy Quran book better than it. Or even you can made a specific part (actually a specific pocket) for it into your bag. So you can make it by cloth or something else. Of course pay attention that the holy Quran should not be beneath the bag in order to keep its respect.

Or as anther suggestion, I suggest you to take another Quran in pocket site which can be portable in your pocket and it is not necessary to put it in the bag. Note that you'd better keep this small Quran in your shirt pocket, not in your trousers pocket (in order to keep it respected). I said these items based on my average knowledge.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking of that option. But still how did the scholars/sahabas carry around the Quran? I am curious. Many of them must know it by-heart. Still they would have carried one around.

Comment: Uh-huh, as you said "Many of them must know it by-heart." , nice point mate. Anyway we should carry it in a respectful way. Moreover, I myself have a Quran relatively in pocket site, and it could be easily portable. But you'd better to find a kind of Quran with the most appropriate hand-writing in order not to make you hard due to its smallness (of its writings).

Comment: You can store the khutma any way you want, no special consideration should be given, unless you do worship the book. As long as you don't mean any disrespect, I don't see any issue with storing it with regular luggage like any other books.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim. I researched a bit further. No, you can't store the Quran in anyway you want to. Hope you understand.

Comment: @0aslam0 I don't, unless its proven by the Quran or Sunnah, which I doubt you can.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim Don't you agree that the Quran should be treated with the at most respect? I also believe we both understand the difference between worshiping and respecting.

Comment: @0aslam0 Sorry I don't think it should be treated with the at most respect. It should be respected, but not with extremism (nothing can be on top of it, kissing it, etc..). If something the prophet never did, or did the opposite of it (like when they used to hide the quran pages under stuff) I don't agree with it.